# Check sbatch script of running job

Tags: slurm, hpc

When running an slurm job from an sbatch script, is there a command that lets me see what was in the sbatch script that I used to start this job?
For example sacct tells me I'm on SLURM_JOB_ID.3 and I would like to see how many job steps there will be in total.

I'm looking for a command that takes the job id and prints the sbatch script it is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
scontrol write batch_script SLURM_JOB_ID
```

The above will display the submission script for job identified with jobid 12345

More info: https://slurm.schedmd.com/scontrol.html#OPT_write-batch_script

Comment: This command will write to slurm-SLURM_JOB_ID.sh .  If you just want to print / stdout you can append a "-" like this: `scontrol write batch_script SLURM_JOB_ID - `

Answer (score 1):

with more recent Slurm versions you can also use `sacct`:

```
sacct -B -j <jobid>
```

see: https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacct.html#OPT_batch-script